# How to query table using window function in MySql 8.0

Tags: mysql, window-functions, row-number, mysql-8.0

How can I transform first table in the second table using a Mysql 8.0 window function query?

The records are orderd by `col1`. On `col2` every record should have the smallest value (1) until a bigger value is encountered (10) then every record after that should have 10 until a bigger value is encountered (20) and so on...

I tried a window query `MIN(col2) OVER (ORDER BY col1)` and also tried `ROW_NUMBER()` but cannot achieve the result.

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/0hVPxeWG)

| col1 | col2 |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 3 | 1 |
| 11 | 10 |
| 12 | 10 |
| 15 | 1 |
| 20 | 10 |
| 21 | 1 |
| 22 | 20 |
| 22 | 10 |
| 25 | 20 |
| 26 | 10 |

| col1 | col2 |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 3 | 1 |
| 11 | 10 |
| 12 | 10 |
| 15 | 10 |
| 20 | 10 |
| 21 | 10 |
| 22 | 10 |
| 22 | 20 |
| 25 | 20 |
| 26 | 20 |

Comment: I don't understand why window function should be used for simple sorting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT col1,
       MAX(col2) OVER (ORDER BY col1) col2
FROM example
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/Sz9WtcBO)